# Definition of sane

Tags: terminology

Does `sane` have a technical definition in a unix / linux context?

I mean in situations such as this:

```
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
```

Comment: The first definition I learned was in ‘stty sane‘. As in ‘not sick‘.

Comment: “is the way [whatever printed the message] expects”

Answer (score 4):

That is just an abbreviation used by [autotools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system) to describe a not too far out build environment, in which standard Unix tools are available.

Answer (score 0):

The standard English definition:

> (of an undertaking or manner) reasonable; sensible.
>
> —New Oxford American Dictionary

The Webster's Third New International Dictionary has a bit more to say on the subject, from the synonym study (**bolding** added):

> SANE, usually constrasted with *insane*, indicates mental soundness, rationality, and level-headedness **without wild quirks or deep derangements.**

In the context of a "sane build environment," the phrase "without wild quirks" is particularly applicable.

More mechanically, you could define "sane" in this context as: "Not violating the *usual expectations* for the build environment."

---

What those "usual expectations" *are* is an inherently subjective question, unless you have an agreed-upon standard to refer to.

---

In a shell scripting environment, you could say a "sane" scripting environment is one that has tools which comply with [POSIX specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).  But I wouldn't use the word "sane" for this; I would just say a "standard shell environment" or a "POSIX-compliant system."

POSIX is the most widely used standard for UNIX/Linux environments, but to my knowledge it doesn't describe the *build* environment (i.e. C compilers, libraries, etc.) so it may not fit the context you are asking about.

---

If a package installation gave me the message,

> checking whether build environment is sane... yes

I would simply understand it to mean, as a message from the developers:

> **Checking that all our assumptions about the environment are correct,** so we can bail out *now* if they're not, rather than checking these same assumptions continually throughout the rest of our code.